# Playing a sprite sheet animation in Cocos2D-x

Tags: c++, animation, cocos2d-x, spritesheet

I'm trying to create an animation using a sprite sheet in Cocos2D-x. I'm doing the following. The game doesn't crash but the screen is still blank.

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto cacher = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
    cacher->addSpriteFramesWithFile("BatmanRun-hd.plist");

    Sprite* someSprite = Sprite::create();

    // load all the animation frames into an array
    Vector<SpriteFrame*> frames;
    for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "run_" << i << ".png";
        frames.pushBack(cacher->getSpriteFrameByName(ss.str()));
    }

    // play the animation
    Animation* anim = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(frames, 0.05f);
    someSprite->runAction(Animate::create(anim));
    someSprite->setPosition(100, 100);

    this->addChild(someSprite);

    return true;
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Start the sprite with the first frame:

```
auto someSprite = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("run_1.png");
```

Pay attention to the code you use for creating the animation: You are adding frames 2-10. That's ok if it's a single shot animation.

I assume that you want to repeat the animation - just from the name "run". You'll have to add frames 1-10 in the for loop.

```
someSprite->runAction(RepeatForever::create(Animate::create(anim)));
```

Answer (score 0):

don't create a empty sprite node. when you do Sprite::create(), load the first frame as the parameter. 
That is used to init contentSize and bounding-box variable of the sprite. So, that might help.